# Проверка символов на уникальность Python

Tags: python, list, set, строки

есть строка a = “a14b6fh”, как узнать, что все символы уникальны, используя множества и списки.
Сделал способом, приведенным ниже, но не совсем соответствует условию.

```
a = "a14b6fh"
b = []
total = True
for element in a:
    if element in b:
        total = False
    else:
        b += element
if total == True:
    print("Да, все символы уникальны")
else:
    print("Нет, символы не уникальны")
```

Comment: `total = len(a) == len(set(a))`

Comment: спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr ="a14b6fh"
setarr = set(arr)
if len(arr) == len(setarr):
    print("Все элементы уникальны")
else:
    print("Есть одинаковые")
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Можно также использовать метод cловаря fromkeys() для удаления дублей. Идея такая, что ключи словаря могут быть только уникальными. Если использовать set(), то в книгах пишут, что изначальный порядок элементов в коллекции может быть нарушен.

```
 b = [1,2,3,3,3,4,5]
 result = list(dict.fromkeys(b))
 print('*',result)
 
 * [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: спасибо за совет

Comment: Автор задал вопрос _"как узнать, что все символы уникальны"_, а не "как удалить дубли". А это не одно и то же.

Comment: Все верно, SergFSM